# Is there any way to save HTML element class changes made by Jquery in a generated EJS file?

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have a to-do list node project, where each to-do list is saved as an entity in MongoDB, like so:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  items: [String]
});
```

When the user clicks one of the items in the to-do list, it crosses it out by changing the CSS class of the element clicked. When the user refreshes, the class is changed back to how the EJS file renders it.

I want the cross out to be local, i.e, only the person who crossed out an item, will see it crossed out. Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve having separate DB entries for each user?

ex entry:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59bf2fed71c3840508539b29"
    },
    "item": [
        "ayy",
        "yyaa",
        "yyaaaafyyy"
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Is there any way your items from the DB can come with an ID or anything besides just: `['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']` ?

Comment: Show me exactly what an example object/array looks like coming out the DB, with like 3 todo items.

Comment: There is an ID, each to do list has an (auto generated, but accessible) ID.

Comment: @agm1984 
I've edited the post to show an entry

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by a single ID with multiple todo items. We kind of need each one to have an ID that can be checked next time the user reloads the page. I am preparing a solution for you that uses localStorage but you could also use cookies.

Comment: I could do a schema where each to-do list item has an ID for the item, and an ID for the To-do list it belongs to.

Comment: I mean, we could probably force it by creating a function that creates an ID based on the innerText that was put into the <li> or <div> to create a slug, but we are getting pretty serious.

Comment: Yes do that. It should work well if you keep basically your current schema, but push in an object that is like this: `{ _id: 'e4e4bdrbgrb4', item: 'Clean bedroom' }` instead of just pushing in 'Clean bedroom'

Comment: or even an auto-incrementing ID, just something unique to each item. i'm going to use it like this `<li id="<%- item_id %>">Clean bedroom</li>`. My goal is to create an event listener on the LI element but I need a way to identify the LI that is already on the page.

Comment: Then, I'm going to set the item into localStorage when it is clicked and crossed off, so the browser will remember it until the user clears it out.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized we can probably do it without identifying them until the moment when the user clicks on the todo item, but note that unique IDs are generally excellent regardless. React JS forces you to put a key on each list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a functional solution:

Backend

```
app.get('/testing', (req, res, next) => {
    const todoItems = {
        '_id': {
            '$oid': '59bf2fed71c3840508539b29'
        },
        'items': [
            { id: 0, todo: 'ayy' },
            { id: 1, todo: 'yyaa' },
            { id: 2, todo: 'yyaaaafyyy' }
        ],
        '__v': 0
    }

    res.render('testing', {
        todoItems
    })
})
```

Frontend

```
<style>
    .complete {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
</style>
```

Place your items into a list. An event listener will be added to every `<li>` element that is inside the element with ID: #todo

```
<ul id="todo">
    <% todoItems.items.forEach((item) => { %>
        <li id="<%- item.id %>">
            <%= item.todo %>
        </li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

This is some JavaScript to place just above `</body>`

```
<script>
    // Define a function that takes input of an HTML element
    // and then toggles the CSS class
    // then checks localStorage to see if the item is in it
    // if not, add it
    // if so, remove it
    const toggleComplete = (item) => {
        item.classList.toggle('complete')
        const isComplete = localStorage.getItem(item.innerText)
        if (!isComplete) {
            localStorage.setItem(item.innerText, 'complete')
            return
        }
        localStorage.removeItem(item.innerText)
    }

    // When the page loads, add an event listener to each <li>
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('#todo li')
    items.forEach((item) => item.addEventListener('click', () => toggleComplete(item)))

    // If the user leaves and comes back, we reinitialize
    // We step through the same array we add event listeners to
    // if the todo item is in localStorage, add the CSS class
    const reinitializeSession = () => {
        items.forEach((item) => {
            const isComplete = localStorage.getItem(item.innerText)
            if (!isComplete) return
            item.classList.add('complete')
        })
    }
    reinitializeSession()
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to implement this, I would like you to type it all out without pasting anything. Start in the JavaScript portion by writing the `const items` part and console log it so you can see what comes out, then write the toggleComplete() function starting with it only doing `console.log('firing this'), then add the rest, then see how the page responds, then finally add the reinitializeSession() function. :)

Comment: That worked perfectly! I really appreciated the comments in the code so I actually know whats going on!